# Nested Function Hanging Up

Tags: php

How do you nest a function that loops?

I am trying to make a function to count the number of sub-categories and count the sub-categories within.

```
<?php

function hier_data( $parent_category = 0, $category_count = 0 ) {

    global $db_connect;

    // Select query
    $query = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            " . DB_PFIX . "product_categories
        WHERE
            category_parent = '" . $parent_category . "'
    ";

    // Return results
    if( $results = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query ) ) {
        while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) {

            $category_count = $category_count + 1;

            $category_count = hier_data( $result["category_id"], $category_count );
        }
    }

    return $category_count;

}

?>
```

Notice: the function works to count one subcategory only if I remove the line `hier_data( $result["category_id"], $category_count );` in the while loop under the query results. However I cannot get the function to loop itself to count the sub-categories sub-cats.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea anyway.. can you not do it in 1 query? Or at least use `COUNT` in your query?

Comment: Is it possible to do this using joins?

Comment: For each category it needs to be able to count the sub-categories at an unlimited depth.

Answer (score 1):

you could get the count using a sub query or a join but that means doing the count for every row. So its probably a good idea to run a separate query like:

```
  "SELECT COUNT(*)," , category
    FROM " . DB_PFIX . "product_categories
    WHERE category_parent = '" . $parent_category . "'
    GROUP BY category";
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't have any luck. Curious as to why my nested function doesn't work though. Obviously its causing a endless loop but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I edited the answer as i made a mistake, ps I don't know if you have column called `category` so I guessed the name

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around  what will happen by calling a function recursively inside a while loop but it seems like a very difficult approach to manage

Comment: Well the while loop is within an if loop for the results of the query. If their are no results then it doesn't enter the while loop. It checks the main category for sub-categories. If a match is found it will count the sub-categories and for each sub-category it will check to see if it has any sub-categories.